# Is it possible to rename file properties in Windows?

Tags: windows, metadata

### QUESTION

Is there any way to rename a file property in Windows (i.e. change a property's display name)?

### EXAMPLE

| Canonical (internal) Name | CURRENT Display Name | DESIRED Display Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `System.Video.EncodingBitrate` | ❌ Data rate | ✅ Video bitrate |
| `System.Audio.EncodingBitrate` | ❌ Bit rate | ✅ Audio bitrate |

[image: How properties currently show]
[image: How would like properties to show]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is possible without hooking deep into the internals of Windows.

Comment: Why you want to change the text ?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks  //  Prem - Well, as you can see the current names are somewhat vague. It can be frustrating sorting videos by what Windows calls "Bit rate", to find this only represents the audio bitrate of the video, then searching through the 300+ Windows properties for the video bit rate only to finally remember that it's called "data rate"

Comment: The "names" are standardized (at least on that version of Windows) hence if you change it , you will frustrate others who will be looking for the original "names". If it is just you , then just keep a reference text file with the "names" to look up. Alternately , EITHER use Visual Basic to make your own "Properties Viewer" with your own names OR use Media Players like VLC which may have the "names" more to your liking OR use other file managers to replace Windows Explorer.

Comment: That's what I do currently, I have an Excel sheet with all the info on the properties and a few others utils. But this approach has several downsides and hence the reason why I raised the question in the first place.